# Pass texture with float values to shader

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml, glsl

I am developing an application in C++ in QT QML 3D. I need to pass tens of float values (or vectors of float numbers) to fragment shader. These values are positions and colors of lights, so I need values more then range from 0.0 to 1.0. However, there is no support to pass an array of floats or integers to a shader in QML. My idea is to save floats to a texture, pass the texture to a shader and get the values from that.

I tried something like this:

```
float array [4] = {100.5, 60.05, 63.013, 0.0};
uchar data [sizeof array * sizeof(float)];
memcpy(data, &array, sizeof array * sizeof(float));
QImage img(data, 4, 1, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
```

and pass this QImage to a fragment shader as sampler2D. But is there there a method like memcpy to get values from texture in GLSL?
texelFetch method only returns me vec4 with float numbers range 0.0 to 1.0. So  how can I get the original value from the texture in a shader?
I prefer to use sampler2D type, however, is there any other type supporting direct memory access in GLSL?

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I don't have any problem to create the QImage with correct float values. I have a problem to access these values in a shader (in GLSL).

Answer (score 4):

This will create a float texture from a float array.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, &array);
```

You can access float values from your fragment shader like this:

```
uniform sampler2D float_texture;

...

float float_texel = float( texture2D(float_texture, tex_coords.xy) );
```

"OpenGL float texture" is a well documented subject.
[What exactly is a floating point texture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709023/what-exactly-is-a-floating-point-texture)

Comment: Hi, could you please expand your answer on *how to access the values from the fragment shader*? To me it seems this might be applicable to my problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301962/passing-qml-array-to-shadereffect

Comment: When I use       glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, &array);    I must pass the created texture to shader like this:     GLuint texture_sampler_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderprogram, "texture");   glUniform1f(texture_sampler_loc, 1); But in the QML I can not get pointer to shader program. Or is there any other way how to pass the texture to shader?

Answer (score 2):

The texture accessing functions *do* directly read from the texture. The problem is that `Format_ARGB32` is not 32-bits *per channel*; it's 32-bits *per pixel*. From [this documentation page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html), it seems clear that `QImage` *cannot* create floating-point images; it only deals in normalized formats. `QImage` itself seems to be a class intended for dealing with GUI matters, not for loading OpenGL images.

You'll have to ditch Qt image shortcuts and actually use OpenGL directly.

Comment: When I created the QImage like above, the values are saved there, but not organized per pixel. So that is why I need some function like memcpy in GLSL, which doesn't access the texture per pixel or texel, but just copy the bytes to any array. Is there some function like this?

Comment: @david: The *are* organized per-pixel. It's just that Qt is interpreting those pixels as 8-bit-per-channel normalized integers, instead of 32-bit-per-channel floats. OpenGL can do exactly what you need; just use it *correctly*.